# Access parent attributes through child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models here, Groups and Posts. Posts belong to group and groups have many posts. Here is my issue. I have an index page of groups. I'm trying to have a sidebar display a list of latest posts. I am unable to link to the posts because of the nested routes (I can't get the correct parameter for the group because this is all appearing on the group index page). Here is how I first tried to do it:

```
<% @latest_posts.each do |post| %>
  <li><%= link_to post.title, group_post_path(@group, post) %></li>
  <li><%= post.group.title %></li>
<% end %>
```

I've already looped through the list of groups on this same view, though:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>

  <div class="table-cell">
    <%= link_to group.title, group %>
  </div>

  <div class="table-cell">
    <%= group.description.truncate(70) %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

So in my groups controller, I can't just make a @group instance variable to place into the group_post_path params. Here's my controller:

```
def index
  @latest_posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(20)
  @groups = Group.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(25)
end
```

So I have two problems. My main one is that I can't link to the post. I thought this would work, but no to that one also (I have friendly id set up, so I need to link to the group name instead of the id here.)

```
<%= link_to post.title, group_post_path(post.group_id, post) %>
```

But any attribute from the parent isn't available.

```
<%= post.group.title %>
```

produces

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

The same goes for trying it in the params.

```
<%= link_to post.title, group_post_path(post.group.title, post) %>
```

My models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
```

How can I get at least access to the parent attributes?

Comment: `group` is `nil`, which in all likelyhood means that the `group_id` is `null` in the database for that record.

Comment: All the posts have group ids. Here's one from the console, for example. ```#<Post id: 30, title: "Does this save?", content: "Does it? I need to know.", group_id: 15, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-06-18 00:25:05", updated_at: "2017-06-18 00:25:17", slug: "total-danarchy-does-this-save", category_id: nil>```

Comment: What do you mean by *I thought this would work, but no to that one also*? Do you get an error message? Are the links just broken? Furthermore: How did you verify that each `post` has a `group_id` that points to an existing `group`?

Comment: First of all why are you defining `posts` separately? `group.posts` will give you posts.Moreover you get the `group` so you can use it in the `link`

Comment: ```undefined method `posts' for #<Class:0x000000064604f0>``` in group controller when I try ```@latest_posts = Group.posts.order('created_at DESC').limit(20)```

Comment: I'm trying to get all posts for all groups. Also to @spickermann, I've verified they all have group_ids. I did update the question with more info.

Comment: No, I mean in the view, where you are looping `@groups`. Inside you can access posts like `group.posts`

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to make a sidebar like the Hot Network Questions here. I'm only doing latest posts for now, but eventually I will change it to popular posts. I need the post list to stand alone from the group list.

Comment: Verifying that all posts have a group_id is a different thing to verifying that all posts have a group. Try `Post.includes(:group).where(groups: {id: nil})` to find all the posts that do not have a group.

Comment: Now you've officially lost me. I don't understand what's happening at this point. But the console returns all records from that.

Comment: So I think that if you destroy a Group, it is not destroying the associated Posts. Or maybe you are deleting the Groups and not destroying them. But whatever the cause, you have Post instances with group_id values that do not associate with a Group -- that is the cause of the error you are seeing. You probably want `dependent: destroy` on the association, and you need to destroy the orphaned Post instances -- then you should be good.

Comment: That was the problem right there. Something I never would have thought about. Thank you.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, David Aldridge, I'll go ahead and mark it.